# Execution time difference between x += y and x = x + y

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I was trying to submit my solution to a leetcode problem wherein `x` and `y` are lists and using

```
x = x + y
```

gave me a **Time limit exceeded**
whereas
using

```
x += y
```

passed the test cases and gave me **AC**.

What is the execution time difference between the two and the difference in the way both are executed?

Comment: There is a magic-named shortcut function for `+=`  that can do an append in place.  Your first option has to create a brand new list and replace the first list.

Comment: `+=` calls `__iadd__` if defined, then falls back to `__add__`. `a+b` calls `__add__`. In some cases, it's the same. In the case of a list, `__iadd__` presumably calls `extend`, so avoids copying `temp` to a new list

Answer (score 13):

For list objects,

```
temp = temp + []
```

Creates a *new list*, and takes linear time *on the size of the resulting list* (it scales **linearly**). Importantly, it re-creates the *entire new list*. If done in a loop, e.g.

```
x = []

for i in range(N):
    x = x + [i]
```

The entire algorithm is *quadratic time*, O(N^2)

On the other hand, `temp += []` works in-place. It does not create a new list. It is O(K) where K is the size of the list on the right, i.e. the number of elements added. This works this way because python list objects are implemented as array-lists which *overallocate* so you don't have to *reallocate* each time the list increases in size. Simply put, this means that appending an item to the end of the list is *amortized constant time*. Importantly, this makes:

```
x = []

for i in range(N):
    x += [i]
```

*linear time*, i.e. O(N).

To see this behavior empirically, you could use the following script:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

def concatenate(N):
    result = []
    for i in range(N):
        result = result + [i]

def inplace(N):
    result = []
    for i in range(N):
        result += [i]


def time_func(N, f):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    f(N)
    stop = time.perf_counter()
    return stop - start

NS = range(0, 100_001, 10_000)
inplc = [time_func(n, inplace) for n in NS]
concat = [time_func(n, concatenate) for n in NS]

df = pd.DataFrame({"in-place":inplc, "concat": concat}, index=NS)

df.plot()
plt.savefig('in-place-vs-new-list-loop.png')
```

[image]

Notice, at a `N == 100_000`, the concatenation version is taking over 10 seconds, whereas the in-place extend version takes 0.01 seconds... so it's several orders of magnitude slower, and the difference will keep growing dramatically (i.e. quadratically) as N increases.

To understand this behavior, here is an informal treatment of the time complexity:

For concat, at each iteration, `x = x + [i]` takes `i` amount of work, where `i` is the *length of the resulting array*. So the whole loop will be `0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N`. Now, using the [handy formula for the Nth partial sum of this well-known series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) the loop will require N*(N+1)/2 total work.

N*(N + 1) / 2 == N^2/2 + N/2 which is simply O(N^2)

On the other hand, the in-place extend version, on each iteration,

```
temp += [i]
```

Requires only *1* (**constant**) amount of work. So for the whole loop, it's just

1 + 1 + ... + 1 (N times)

So N total amount of work, so it is O(N)

Comment: This is a *fantastic* answer. However, I think this question is a clear duplicate of at least the first two dupe targets that I've added. I am willing to merge this question into one of those, which will carry your answer over there, too, in order to preserve it and make it more visible. Please let me know if you'd like me to do the merge. (And please make any cosmetic edits that might be necessary to make your answer match the target question.)

Answer (score 4):

The expression `a = a + b` does the following:

1. Allocate a new list big enough to hold both `a` and `b`.
2. Copy `a` to the new buffer.
3. Copy `b` to the new buffer.
4. Bind the name `a` to the new buffer (which is what `list.__add__` returns).

The allocation and copies are inevitable in this case, regardless of the fact that `b` is empty.

The expression `a += b` is roughly equivalent to `list.extend` with an assignment at the end:

1. Extend the buffer of `a` by enough elements to hold `b`. This does not always involve a reallocation, because list growth is amortized to take `O(n)` time in the long run.
2. Copy `b` to the end of `a`.
3. Rebind the name `a` to the same object (which is what `list.__iadd__` returns).

Notice that in this case, step is is a **re**allocation, so elements of `a` are copied only when the memory moves. Since `b` is empty in your case, nothing is reallocated or copied at all.